# Crystal oscilator not oscilating on a PIC

Tags: pic, oscillator, crystal

I am experimenting with a PIC16F84A at the moment.

I can get this working fine using an RC network for the clock.

When I switch to using a crystal (the usual xtal across pins 15&16 with 2 caps going to ground from the same pins) I am not getting any clock at all.

The PIC is the 20MHz version, and I have tried all the crystals I have - 4MHz, 14.3MHz and 25MHz, and numerous different capacitors rangeing from 22pf right up into the uF range, but all I get is what appears to be a logic high on pin 15 and a logic low on pin 16.

Yes, I have changed the program config to be _XT_OSC (I have tried them all), but to no avail.

I am using gpasm to assemble the program and pk2cmd to flash the PIC in circuit under Ubuntu.

Any clues?

Edit: diagram:

```
            22pf
16 o----+---||----+
        |         |
        -         |
       |=|Xtal    +---+
        -         |   |
        |         |   _
15 o----+---||----+   - GND
            22pf
```

(a little crude, I know ;) )

Comment: Can we see a circuit diagram please of how its wired up.

Comment: 22pF may be even too high. Try 12-18pf range. Also, are you using a breadbord?

Comment: Yes, I am using a breadboard.  And I think 22pf may be my smallest cap available at the moment.

Comment: Ohkay - if I run it in HS oscillator mode, and ditch the capacitors (just have a crystal linked between pins 15 and 16) I get it working.  If I then add the capacitors it stalls.  Well, I say stalls - it appears to possibly be working at about 0.1Hz.

Comment: Solderless breadboards can be troublesome, especially for circuits involving crystal oscillators; I never use them. Try putting it on a PCB.

Comment: Do not stay too long with the 16F84.  It is obsolete, expensive, limited in capability. Try 16F88 instead: http://www.finitesite.com/d3jsys/16F88.html

Comment: How do you know you have no clock? Many scopes will kill the ossc when connected. Make sure you are on the 10x setting and have 10 meg input or more.

Comment: @markrages yeah, I know, but it's the best I could get locally.  I am going to get some of the newer flash PICs with built-in USB2 soon, when I can find somewhere to get one from.

Comment: @russ_hensel,I'm looking at CLKOUT, the clock/4 output from the PIC

Comment: @Matt, isn't CLKOUT the same pin as one of the oscillator pins? I thought it was multiplexed. You only use it for an external RC oscillator, or the internal FRC. But that might only apply for the 24F/H and dsPIC series which have a PLL.

Comment: microchipdirect.com is the best place to buy PICs. Every distributor has some as well.  And Microchip is pretty generous with the free samples.

Comment: @russ_hensel, That is true (it is shared) but I can measure the clock on it with a crystal attached.  And regardless of that, with the xtal+2caps the program doesn't run.  Without the caps it runs beautifully.

Comment: @markrages does that include the UK?

Comment: microchipdirect (and their samples) ship from Thailand. I'm not familiar with all the UK distributors, but Farnell appears to list a couple thousand types of PIC.

Comment: Well, this is my first PIC, and I'm mighty proud of what I have done given I've never programmed on before.  I have interfaced an 8 channel ADC0838 serial ADC to the PIC on port A, and port B links to a pair of 7 segment displays via two MC14495 hex drivers, and the LEDs display a hex representation of the ADC's channel 1 input.  Now if I could somehow combine the /CE and CLK signals from the PIC to the ADC I'd be only using 2 lines of port A instead of 3.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the tip about the free samples - I now have 2 'F88s and an 'F777 on their way for me to play with.

Comment: @MattJenkins, it is actually the input capacitance and inductance of the scope probe that often kills the xtal when you touch it. Second, as pointed out, too much capacitance can often be a larger issue then too little.

Comment: @Matt, I live in the UK and Microchip Direct are great. They handle paying VAT and shipping direct from Thailand. I've bought from them before and their service is great, and prices are very competitive with distributors.

Comment: Ok, putting it on a bit of stripboard has done the trick.  I guess the tracks on the breadboard have quite a high capacitance of their own.  Thanks all.  Btw, 22pf is good.  The datasheet says anywhere between 15pF and 33pf for 4mhz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have too much capacitance on the oscillator pins this can be caused by:

1. Using the wrong capacitors for the selected oscillator/crystal.
2. Building your circuit on a breadboard which increases capacitance in the circuit.
3. Connecting a scope probe to the oscillator circuit.

When measuring the oscillator frequency it is best to connect the probe to the oscillator through a buffer. The PIC microprocessors often have a CLKOUT pin that serves this function, but it can only be used in some oscillator modes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 1Meg Ohm resistor in parallel with your xtal

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: I think what he's thinking of is a bias resistor to keep the CMOS inverter near its threshold region.  This is necessary when using a CMOS inverter as the gain element in a crystal oscillator.  PICs already have this built in.  I've done over 100 PIC projects and never needed to add a external bias resistor.  However, I have seen Microchip mention it on occasion.  I don't think this was a dumb suggestion deserving a downvote, so I'm upvoting it to cancel that out.

Comment: @Olin - I guess it was downvoted for lacking detail, not for being wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I've always been able to solve this problem by reducing, or often *totally eliminating* the capacitors. I've had this problem more times than I care to count, but it's never failed to fix the problem.

Comment: Hm, I don't know if I can recommend this. My experience is that on most oscillators this has an adverse effect.

Comment: I agree with stevenvh.  Without any caps it could start oscillating at overtone frequencies.  Also, without the right load on the crystal, the frequency will likely be a little out of spec, even if it oscillates at the fundamental.